# Appending a class to a javascript calendar given the data (clndr.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I am looking to assign a class to each clndr.js event that appears in my calendar based on the value itself. `var temp` shows an example of the data received. I want to the style each event on type being 1 or 2. The code shows the default template which I want to modify to simply add in the value passed in `type` as a class so I can then style it.

[link to the source library on github](https://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR)

[link to a similar problem on github](https://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR/issues/6)

```
// This is the default calendar template. This can be overridden.
var clndrTemplate =
    "<div class='clndr-controls'>" +
        "<div class='clndr-control-button'>" +
            "<span class='clndr-previous-button'>previous</span>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='month'><%= month %> <%= year %></div>" +
        "<div class='clndr-control-button rightalign'>" +
            "<span class='clndr-next-button'>next</span>" +
        "</div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "<table class='clndr-table' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>" +
        "<thead>" +
            "<tr class='header-days'>" +
            "<% for(var i = 0; i < daysOfTheWeek.length; i++) { %>" +
                "<td class='header-day'><%= daysOfTheWeek[i] %></td>" +
            "<% } %>" +
            "</tr>" +
        "</thead>" +
        "<tbody>" +
        "<% for(var i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++){ %>" +
            "<tr>" +
            "<% for(var j = 0; j < 7; j++){ %>" +
            "<% var d = j + i * 7; %>" +
                "<td class='<%= days[d].classes %>'>" +
                    "<div class='day-contents <%= days[d].type %>'><%= days[d].day %></div>" +
                "</td>" +
            "<% } %>" +
            "</tr>" +
        "<% } %>" +
        "</tbody>" +
    "</table>";
```

```js
var calendars = {};
$(document).ready(function () {
    var thisMonth = moment().format('YYYY-MM');
    var eventArray = {{ data|tojson }};
    var temp = [{
        date: thisMonth + '-22',
        type: 1
    }, {
        date: thisMonth + '-27',
        type: 2
    }, {
        date: thisMonth + '-13',
        type: 1
    }];
    calendars.clndr1 = $('.cal1').clndr({
        events: eventArray,
        targets: {
            day: 'day',
        },
        clickEvents: {
            click: function (target) {
                console.log('Cal-1 clicked: ', target);
            },
            today: function () {
                console.log('Cal-1 today');
            },
            nextMonth: function () {
                console.log('Cal-1 next month');
            },
            previousMonth: function () {
                console.log('Cal-1 previous month');
            },
            onMonthChange: function () {
                console.log('Cal-1 month changed');
            },
            nextYear: function () {
                console.log('Cal-1 next year');
            },
            previousYear: function () {
                console.log('Cal-1 previous year');
            },
            onYearChange: function () {
                console.log('Cal-1 year changed');
            },
            nextInterval: function () {
                console.log('Cal-1 next interval');
            },
            previousInterval: function () {
                console.log('Cal-1 previous interval');
            },
            onIntervalChange: function () {
                console.log('Cal-1 interval changed');
            }
        },
        multiDayEvents: {
            singleDay: 'date',
            endDate: 'endDate',
            startDate: 'startDate'
        },
        showAdjacentMonths: true,
        adjacentDaysChangeMonth: false
    });
    // Bind all clndrs to the left and right arrow keys
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        // Left arrow
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            calendars.clndr1.back();
            calendars.clndr2.back();
            calendars.clndr3.back();
        }
        // Right arrow
        if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            calendars.clndr1.forward();
            calendars.clndr2.forward();
            calendars.clndr3.forward();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code, so I'm working with the test of CLNDR from github - folder "tests".

Add at the bottom of test.js (basically just make sure it's after `clndr` activation)

```
var thisMonth = moment().format('YYYY-MM');

var temp = [{
    date: thisMonth + '-22',
    type: 1
}, {
    date: thisMonth + '-27',
    type: 2
}, {
    date: thisMonth + '-13',
    type: 1
}];
for (event of temp) {
    $('.calendar-day-' + event.date).addClass('ev-type-' + event.type);
};
```

Then add some css styles to test.html `<head>` just to clearly see it's working

```
.ev-type-1 {
    background: #F00 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
.ev-type-2 {
    background: #0F0 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ales, thanks for coming back to me on this. If you look at the src/clndr.js file then you will see the code that I am working with. The template is the default one in that file. I am not quite sure I understand where you place the javascript you have added.

Comment: in clndr.js is source of the plugin, but you don't need to edit this. You need to add the code I posted where you actually activate the plugin, so for example after "$(document).keydown..." block in your code.